# How to write a unit test case for below scenario in Angular Jasmine?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

main.service.ts

```
    public validateUser (serviceCall : any, data: object, callback: Function ){
      this.httpclient.post<any>(serviceCall , data).toPromise().then((res) => {
      callback(res, null);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      callback(null,res);
    });
```

main.component.ts

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this.userDetails = new UserDetails();
      this.userDetails.userName = "<userName>";
      this.userDetails.userPwd= "<userPwd>";

      this.mainService.vaidateUser(this.serviceUtil.REST_API_URL, this.userDetails, 
      this._processResponse.bind(this));

    }

    _processResponse(res: any, err: null ) {
    if (err == null && res != null ) {
       this.isLoginSuccessFull = res.response;
    } else {
      this.isLoginSuccessFull = false;
    }
```

main.component.spec.ts

What I am trying to do is as below :

```
    it("should hit API and get success response ", () => {
     this.userDetailsMock.userName = "<userName>";
     this.userDetailsMock.userPwd  = "<userPwd>";

     let bindedFunction = spyOn(component_processResponse as CallbackFunction, "bind");
     this.mainService.validateUser(this.serviceUtil.REST_API_URL, this.userDetailsMock, bindedFunction);
      let res = this.httpMock.expectOne({
        'url' : this.serviceUtil.REST_API_URL,
         'method' : "POST"
      });
     res.flush(result);
      expect(component.isLoginSuccessFull).toBeEqual(result);
     }
    });
```

But this does not seems to working and I'm thinking I'm way away from solutions. I'm pretty new in unit testing module in jasmine - angular. Gow can I write a unit test case for this scenario?

In my component while making service call via main.service file, I'm passing `_processResponse` function with current component context. I service after getting response from backend API, I'm checking calling this function (callBack(res, err)).